# Erro: "unexpected T_STRING" no PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Peguei uma função da internet pra calcular a diferença entre as datas.
Criei um classe pra facilitar, porque vou usar essa função em outras telas.

**Versão do PHP: 5.2.***

Código chamando a classe:

```
  include("funcoes/datahora.php");
  $datahora = new dataHora();
```

O erro é esse:

[image: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a6483778/public_html/funcoes/datahora.php on line 1]

Segue meu código em PHP:

```php
<?php // <-- O erro está aqui, na primeira linha!
class dataHora {    
    function data($data){ 
        $data_atual = mktime(); 

        list($ano,$mes,$dia) = explode("-",$data);
        list($dia,$hora) = explode(" ",$dia);
        list($hora,$min,$seg) = explode(":",$hora);

        $data_banco = mktime($hora,$min,$seg,$mes,$dia,$ano); 

        $diferenca = $data_atual - $data_banco; 

        $minutos = $diferenca/60; 
        $horas = $diferenca/3600; 
        $dias = $diferenca/86400; 


        if($minutos < 1){ 
            $diferenca = "há alguns segundos. Mais precisamente: ".$diferenca." segundos";
        } elseif($minutos > 1 && $horas < 1) { 
            if(floor($minutos) == 1 or floor($horas) == 1){ $s = ''; } else { $s = 's'; } 
            $diferenca = "há ".floor($minutos)." minuto".$s;
        } elseif($horas <= 24) { 
            if(floor($horas) == 1){ $s = ''; } else { $s = 's'; } 
            $diferenca = "há ".floor($horas)." hora".$s;
        } elseif($dias <= 2){ 
            $diferenca = "ontem";
        } elseif($dias <= 7){ 
            $diferenca = "há ".floor($dias)." dias";
        } elseif($dias <= 8){
            $diferenca = "há uma semana";
        } else {
            $diferenca = date("d/m/Y",$data_banco);
        } 

        return $diferenca; 
    }    
}
?>
```

[Código fonte](http://codigofonte.uol.com.br/codigos/calcular-diferenca-entre-datas-e-mostrar-uma-mensagem-personalizada)

Comment: Pode postar/evidenciar a **linha do erro e a anterior**, parece que uma aspa não foi fechada.

Comment: Isso mesmo @perdeu, provavelmente está faltando ou sobrando um delimitador de String. Porém não está no código postado, pois [ele não tem erro de sintaxe](http://codepad.org/21PqeBFv).

Comment: Atualizado! @perdeu

Comment: Esse código roda em um servidor linux? o arquivo foi criado no windows?

Comment: Foi criado no windows, e não tenho certeza se é servidor linux, @perdeu

Comment: Crie um arquivo novo e coloque `phpinfo()` isso vai mostrar o sistema operacional.

Comment: Leonardo, o erro pode ser de *encoding*, já que o arquivo possui acentos. Tente usar o Notepad++ ou algum editor e convertê-lo para UTF-8. Ou ainda ele pode ter sido danificado na transferência via FTP. Já tentou enviar de novo?

Comment: Acredito que sei o que é, teste utilizar a tag `<?` no início e a tag `?>` no final, ao invés de `<?php` no início e `?>` no final, pra ver se o erro some.

Comment: @perdeu. Sim, é Linux!

Comment: Não consegui reproduzir o seu erro, aqui na minha maquina funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: O que o @utluiz, sugeriu deu certo, kkkk. Fiz o upload de novo e funcionou perfeitamente, acho que na hora de fazer a transferência, deve ter danificado o arquivo. Valeo !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiz upload de novo e por incrível que pareça, funcionou. Acho que na hora de transferir o arquivo, deve ter danificado.

**Obrigado pela ajuda!**

Comment: O protocolo FTP tem sérios problemas quando se pensa sobre a integridade do arquivo. Em várias hospedagens já tive problemas, por exemplo, ao enviar vários arquivos em *batch*, vários deles **aleatoriamente** ficarem corrompidos. Se o seu servidor suportar, utilize um protocolo melhor como SSH com um *client* como [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Segundo essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463887/parse-error-syntax-error-unexpected-t-string-on-line-1), o problema está nos caractres de quebra de linha que no windows é representando como `\r\n`e no linux apenas `\n`

> Eu consertei. Escrevendo o código no Windows implicava ter \ r \ n
>   como caracteres de quebra linha, que não foram intepretados corretamente
>   na minha hospedagem Linux: convertei todos \ r \ n para o padrão UNIX
>   de quebra  linha de caractere \ n e corrigi o erro.

Comment: Em alguma situação específica isso até pode causar o problema, mas eu sempre compactei meus arquivos PHP removendo quebras de linha sem dificuldades. Veja [aqui](http://codepad.org/w2LxEBMX) o arquivo da pergunta sem quebras de linha.